# How to download images in Android present inside a Resource folder

Tags: android, android-volley, picasso, android-resources, android-download-manager

How to Implement a download function in Android that download images present inside resource folder.

**My research on this topic:**I gone through volley and Picasso library tutorials but these helps to download the images from the URL.

I am pretty much new to Android and stack overflow so if any mistakes made then please excuse me

Comment: You call that download? Google for android how to copy file from resource.

Comment: Do you mean, how to use the images you have placed in your resources/drawable folders?